# How to iterate over three or more lists, comparing each with each element?

Tags: python, numpy, python-itertools

I have several lists, each with a dictionary. I need to go through each combination of elements and compare them with each other. I want to get something like this:

```py
arr1 = [1, 2, 3]
arr2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
arr3 = [-1, -2]

for a, b in magic_function(arr1, arr2, arr3, ...):  # Probably even more lists!
    print(a, b)

# Output:

(1, 'a')
(1, 'b')
(1, 'c')
(1, 'd')
(2, 'a')
(2, 'b')
(2, 'c')
(2, 'd')
(3, 'a')
(3, 'b')
(3, 'c')
(3, 'd')
('a', -1)
('a', -2)
('b', -1)
('b', -2)
('c', -1)
('c', -2)
('d', -1)
('d', -2)
(1, -1)
(1, -2)
(2, -1)
(2, -2)
(3, -1)
(3, -2)
```

What function can i use for this? I found `itertools.product()`, but that is not quite what I want. I can also use numpy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import itertools

arrs = [[1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], [-1, -2]]
for arr1, arr2 in itertools.combinations(arrs, 2):
    for p in itertools.product(arr1, arr2):
        print(p)
```